# how to iterate through multiple select options with jquery

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering if it's possible to go through multiple select options and get their values and text(if one is selected get the value and text, if 2 is selected get both of their values and text and so on)

I have 15 select boxes in one page?

any help would be appreciated.

```
 <form>
        <select class="select" name="select3" id="select3">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1.99">1</option>
          <option value="1.99">2</option>
          <option value="1.99">3</option>
          <option value="1.99">4</option>
          <option value="1.99">5</option>
          <option value="1.99">6</option>
          <option value="1.99">7</option>
          <option value="1.99">8</option>
        </select>
        </form>

  <form> 
      <select  class="select" name="select" id="select">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1.99">1</option>
            <option value="1.99">2</option>
            <option value="1.99">3</option>
            <option value="1.99">4</option>
            <option value="1.99">5</option>
            <option value="1.99">6</option>
            <option value="1.99">7</option>
            <option value="1.99">8</option>
          </select>
   </form>
```

all the select options have the same class.

thanks

Answer (score 52):

This will alert all the selected options' text and values (for all selects on the page):

```
$('select > option:selected').each(function() {
    alert($(this).text() + ' ' + $(this).val());
});
```

See Core/each and Selectors/selected:

http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/selected

Comment: Its a poorly defined usecase, where the class, name, id and tag are all the same name. $('select >... , $('#select >... , $(.select... will all work

Answer (score 6):

for optgroups...

```
$("select[id^='desu']").children('optgroup').children('option:selected').each( 
    function(id, element) {
        document.write(element.title);
    }
);
```

Comment: aha the children() function - just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

This function will return an array of text/value pairs for the selects matching the given class.

```
function getSelects(klass) {
    var selected = [];
    $('select.' + klass).children('option:selected').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        selected.push( { text: $this.text(), value: $this.val() } );
    });
    return selected;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If all of your select boxes start with a similar id ("select_1", "select_2", "select_3", etc), you can just do:

```
var arr = [];
$("select[id^='select_']").children('option:selected').each(function(){
  //you will do this once for every selected item...
}
```

This allows you to loop through only specific select boxes, in case you have multiple groupings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can I use a .change function as well in the code above, like
.... .change.each(function() {

Comment: well if you wrap the change in an anonymous function yes
.change( function(){
   $('select').each.....
});

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/kmgoddard/Lfkvm3ar/4/

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
list = new Array();
$('select > option:selected').each(function() {

  list.push($(this).val());

});
 alert(list.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Another option

var selected = [];

$('select :has(:selected)').each( function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    selected.push( { text: $this.text(), value: $this.val() );

});

return selected;
```