# How to iterate through multiple select options

Tags: jquery

i have like 50 select boxes.

I like to understand how I can go through all the select boxes that have ids like select_1 select_2 select 3.

Also, I like to go through all the select list and values that were not selected.

Comment: You should probably like provide some HTML and possibly an example of an attempt at iterating that failed for you.

Comment: check `each()` function, try something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to iterate through multiple select options with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227684/how-to-iterate-through-multiple-select-options-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all select drop downs whos id's begin with `select_`, you could do the following

```
$(function(){ 
    $('select[id^="select_"]').each(function(){ 
        $(this).find('option').not(':selected').each(function(){  // iterate over all non selected options 
           console.log( $(this).val() );   // or alert( $(this).val() ); 
        });               
    }); 
 })
```

Comment: mmm question, what happens if you have white spaces in your id?

Answer (score 0):

you can assign class to all selectbox and iterate using `.each()` function 
eg

```
 $('.classname').each(function(){
        $(this).val();//to get the value
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$("select[id*='select_']").css({ "border" : "1px solid red" });
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rx7jE/