# Multi Select Box only shows last selected value

Tags: php, javascript, html, multi-select

I have a multi-select box which allows me to select multiple values and then add them to a second select box when I click on an arrow.  Now this part works fine and I can select multiple values.  However when I pass the values of the second select box to variable, to a PHP page the variable only shows the value of the last item in the list and not all of them.

Javascript Code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">  
   $().ready(function() {  
   $('#add').click(function() {  
   return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
   });  
   $('#remove').click(function() {  
   return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');  
   });  
   });  
   </script>
```

HTML CODE

```
 <form action="insert_email_visitor_list1.php" method="get" name="form1" target="_self" id="form1">

    <select multiple id="select1" class="mulitiselect" name="select1">  
    <option value="1">Date/Time</option>  
    <option value="2">Company</option>  
    <option value="3">Location</option>  
    <option value="4">Nof Pages / Visit</option>
    <option value="5">Traffic Source</option>  
    <option value="6">Search Term</option>  
    <option value="7">Report</option>
    <option value="8">Classification</option>  
    <option value="9">Owner</option>
    <option value="10">Phone</option>
    <option value="11">Town</option>
    <option value="12">City</option>
    <option value="12">Country</option>
    <option value="12">Hostname</option> 
    </select>  


    <a href="#" id="add"><img src="images/add-arrow.png" alt="" /></a>
         selected Columns
    <a href="#" id="remove"><img src="images/remove-arrow.png" alt="" /></a>  


    <select multiple id="select2" name="select2" class="mulitiselect"></select>  

    <div class="bottom-img"><img src="images/popup-bottomimg.png" alt="" /></div>

    <button>
    <img src="images/info-icon.png" alt="" />
    </button>
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

PHP CODE

```
   $select2 = $_GET['select2'];
   echo "$select2";
```

Basically I am just after some advice as to if i am doing this the correct way?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227684/how-to-iterate-through-multiple-select-options-with-jquery ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field you pass to PHP must be named with a `[]`, e.g. `select2[]`. Without that, PHP will treat the passed in values as a single value, and only the LAST value passed in would ever bee put into $_GET.

Using `[]` on the name tells PHP to treat it as a multi-valued field and it will create an array in $_GET, e.g.

```
$_GET['select2'][0] => 'first option selected';
$_GET['select2'][1] => 'second option selected';
```

etc...

Remember that the `multiple` parameter is a purely client-side thing, and PHP has no way of knowing that it was a multi-select. It willy simply see the equivalent of

```
select2=foo&select2=bar&select2=baz
```

arrive in the POST/GET, and select the last value passed in.